# How to use Seq_along for multiple dates from a list in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have been fiddling around with a R project and have hit a roadblock. Ill explain what the goal is, It is to make a set of plots that show points plotted on a map based on their measurement time (water_level_date) and plot accordingly over a pre-selected time period.

The roadblock is that I have hit is that the loop creates other plots but doesn't apply the date restriction. so it produces the same plot 12 times. the loop I am currently using is

```
for (i in c(1:length(date)))
filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")
```

I just was a bit confused about what I should be using for the loop as I am using **for()** for dates and I think that its wrong, I think I have to use **seq_along** but I'm unsure how to get it to loop for a sequence say **01/01/1985** to **01/01/1986**.

The dates are retrieved from a data frame but the issue is that it ignores the dates completely. Any help would be well appreciated. Yes, and I know I don't have a repeatable example just wondering how to properly use seq_along for a list of dates which loops between a start and end date.

DATA

```
structure(list(neg_decimal_lat = c(-35.9580624, -36.0270162, 
-35.9505656, -35.9492215, -35.97803, -35.9766841, -35.9855039, 
-35.98203, -35.984858, -36.0272577, -36.0048864, -35.9731485, 
-35.9701733, -36.0034897, -36.0036909), decimal_long = c(140.3021648, 
140.360413, 140.2858737, 140.2650201, 140.287947, 140.2547256, 
140.2625761, 140.268055, 140.277901, 140.2702671, 140.2628329, 
140.2857832, 140.2663454, 140.2683559, 140.2898351), max_drill_depth = c(67.5, 
27.43, 38.4, 21.3, 18, 22, 67.1, 34, 34, 10.67, 40, 20, 16, 24, 
40), water_level_date = structure(c(120L, 120L, 982L, 1320L, 
1294L, 762L, 1320L, 592L, 729L, 817L, 90L, 1320L, 1320L, 202L, 
631L), .Label = c("", "1/02/1972", "1/02/1985", "1/02/1996", 
"1/02/2006", "1/03/2007", "1/03/2013", "1/04/1976", "1/04/1978", 
"1/04/1985", "1/04/1992", "1/04/1998", "1/04/1999", "1/04/2011", 
"1/05/2013", "1/06/1979", "1/06/1982", "1/06/1983", "1/06/1995", 
"1/06/2000", "1/06/2006", "1/07/1985", "1/07/1986", "1/07/2003", 
"1/07/2004", "1/07/2008", "1/07/2013", "1/08/1972", "1/08/1980", 
"1/08/1983", "1/08/1993", "1/09/1978", "1/09/1998", "1/10/1974", 
"1/10/1975", "1/10/1992", "1/10/1995", "1/10/2008", "1/10/2010", 
"1/11/1974", "1/11/1991", "1/11/1999", "1/12/1971", "1/12/1976", 
"1/12/1983", "1/12/2000", "1/12/2003", "1/12/2009", "10/01/1980", 
"10/01/1997", "10/01/2012", "10/02/1970", "10/02/1980", "10/02/1982", 
"10/03/2011", "10/04/1986", "10/04/1989", "10/04/1991", "10/04/1996", 
"10/04/2002", "10/04/2013", "10/05/1969", "10/05/1988", "10/05/1989", 
"10/06/1998", "10/07/1979", "10/07/1987", "10/07/2002", "10/07/2013", 
"10/08/1976", "10/08/2012", "10/09/1975", "10/09/1979", "10/09/1981", 
"10/09/1988", "10/09/2012", "10/10/1985", "10/10/2005", "10/10/2012", 
"10/11/1969", "10/11/1970", "10/11/1981", "10/11/1988", "10/11/2000", 
"10/11/2004", "10/12/1998", "10/12/2003", "10/12/2004", "10/12/2009", 
"11/01/2008", "11/01/2012", "11/02/1974", "11/03/1970", "11/03/1977", 
"11/03/1983", "11/03/1985", "11/03/1991", "11/03/2003", "11/04/1973", 
"11/04/1975", "11/04/1991", "11/04/1994", "11/04/2013", "11/05/1973", 
"11/05/1982", "11/05/1988", "11/05/2004", "11/05/2011", "11/06/1979", 
"11/06/1981", "11/06/1999", "11/06/2010", "11/06/2013", "11/07/2005", 
"11/07/2013", "11/08/1978", "11/08/1982", "11/08/2004", "11/09/1974", 
"11/09/1978", "11/09/1981", "11/09/1996", "11/09/1997", "11/09/2006", 
"11/10/1978", "11/10/1984", "11/10/1985", "11/10/1989", "11/10/2006", 
"11/10/2008", "11/10/2011", "11/10/2012", "11/11/1981", "11/11/1991", 
"11/12/1967", "11/12/1971", "11/12/1985", "11/12/2001", "11/12/2009", 
"12/01/1979", "12/02/1975", "12/02/1979", "12/03/1971", "12/03/1981", 
"12/03/1997", "12/03/1998", "12/03/2001", "12/03/2003", "12/04/1973", 
"12/04/1977", "12/04/1983", "12/04/2013", "12/05/1982", "12/06/1977", 
"12/06/1987", "12/06/2001", "12/06/2007", "12/06/2013", "12/07/1974", 
"12/07/1983", "12/07/2010", "12/07/2013", "12/08/1991", "12/08/2002", 
"12/08/2013", "12/09/1975", "12/09/1978", "12/09/1980", "12/09/1988", 
"12/09/1997", "12/10/1982", "12/10/1999", "12/10/2000", "12/10/2004", 
"12/10/2006", "12/11/1969", "12/11/1979", "12/11/1997", "12/12/1979", 
"12/12/1988", "12/12/2003", "13/01/1989", "13/01/2013", "13/02/1981", 
"13/02/1985", "13/02/1990", "13/03/1974", "13/03/1998", "13/03/2001", 
"13/03/2003", "13/03/2013", "13/04/1988", "13/04/2004", "13/05/1981", 
"13/05/1983", "13/06/2013", "13/07/1971", "13/07/1987", "13/07/1999", 
"13/07/2010", "13/08/1974", "13/08/1998", "13/08/2013", "13/09/1974", 
"13/09/1978", "13/09/1979", "13/09/1983", "13/09/1984", "13/09/1989", 
"13/09/1990", "13/09/1993", "13/09/1994", "13/09/2000", "13/09/2010", 
"13/10/1998", "13/10/2004", "13/10/2006", "13/10/2008", "13/10/2011", 
"13/11/1996", "13/12/1996", "13/12/1999", "13/12/2001", "13/12/2004", 
"14/01/1977", "14/02/1984", "14/02/1990", "14/03/1994", "14/03/2000", 
"14/03/2001", "14/03/2002", "14/03/2008", "14/03/2012", "14/03/2013", 
"14/04/1980", "14/04/1989", "14/05/1982", "14/05/1983", "14/05/1985", 
"14/05/2002", "14/05/2010", "14/06/1967", "14/06/1968", "14/06/1989", 
"14/06/1996", "14/06/2002", "14/06/2013", "14/07/1983", "14/08/1973", 
"14/08/2013", "14/09/1973", "14/09/1978", "14/09/1993", "14/09/1994", 
"14/09/1998", "14/09/2000", "14/09/2009", "14/10/1986", "14/10/1988", 
"14/10/1997", "14/11/1962", "14/11/1984", "14/11/1986", "14/11/1996", 
"14/11/2000", "14/12/1987", "14/12/1998", "14/12/1999", "14/12/2000", 
"14/12/2001", "15/02/1968", "15/03/1977", "15/03/1979", "15/03/1989", 
"15/03/1991", "15/03/1994", "15/03/1995", "15/03/1996", "15/03/1999", 
"15/03/2000", "15/03/2001", "15/03/2003", "15/03/2010", "15/04/1999", 
"15/04/2009", "15/05/1991", "15/07/1980", "15/07/1982", "15/07/2010", 
"15/07/2013", "15/08/2013", "15/09/1971", "15/09/1975", "15/09/1978", 
"15/09/1989", "15/09/1992", "15/09/1994", "15/09/1995", "15/09/1997", 
"15/09/2000", "15/09/2003", "15/09/2009", "15/10/1993", "15/10/1996", 
"15/10/2002", "15/10/2006", "15/11/1994", "15/11/1996", "15/12/1977", 
"15/12/1983", "15/12/1989", "15/12/1994", "15/12/2000", "15/12/2008", 
"16/01/1979", "16/01/2012", "16/02/1971", "16/02/1978", "16/02/2008", 
"16/03/1977", "16/03/1979", "16/03/1989", "16/03/1991", "16/03/1993", 
"16/03/1998", "16/03/2000", "16/03/2003", "16/03/2007", "16/03/2010", 
"16/04/2008", "16/04/2013", "16/05/1979", "16/05/1996", "16/06/1989", 
"16/06/1992", "16/06/1997", "16/06/2008", "16/07/1974", "16/07/1977", 
"16/07/1982", "16/07/1996", "16/07/2008", "16/07/2013", "16/08/1988", 
"16/08/1995", "16/08/2013", "16/09/1969", "16/09/1976", "16/09/1979", 
"16/09/1993", "16/09/2005", "16/10/1970", "16/10/1986", "16/10/1995", 
"16/10/2001", "16/10/2006", "16/10/2008", "16/11/1981", "16/12/1971", 
"16/12/1979", "16/12/1980", "16/12/2003", "17/01/1974", "17/01/1980", 
"17/01/1985", "17/01/2008", "17/02/1979", "17/03/1972", "17/03/1977", 
"17/03/1998", "17/03/1999", "17/03/2002", "17/03/2010", "17/04/1998", 
"17/04/2007", "17/04/2013", "17/05/1977", "17/05/2002", "17/05/2012", 
"17/06/1977", "17/06/1986", "17/06/2002", "17/06/2013", "17/07/1996", 
"17/07/2008", "17/07/2013", "17/08/1989", "17/08/1990", "17/08/1994", 
"17/09/1969", "17/09/1974", "17/09/1975", "17/09/1984", "17/09/1992", 
"17/09/1993", "17/09/1996", "17/09/1998", "17/09/2008", "17/10/1991", 
"17/10/1994", "17/11/1983", "17/11/1997", "17/12/1985", "17/12/1986", 
"17/12/1991", "17/12/1997", "17/12/1999", "17/12/2009", "17/12/2012", 
"18/01/1972", "18/01/1977", "18/01/1984", "18/01/1995", "18/01/2005", 
"18/01/2007", "18/02/1975", "18/02/2008", "18/03/1973", "18/03/1977", 
"18/03/1996", "18/03/1998", "18/03/2009", "18/03/2010", "18/03/2013", 
"18/04/1996", "18/04/2000", "18/04/2013", "18/05/1990", "18/06/2002", 
"18/06/2008", "18/06/2010", "18/06/2013", "18/07/1973", "18/07/2000", 
"18/08/1979", "18/08/1983", "18/09/1978", "18/09/1991", "18/09/1992", 
"18/09/1996", "18/09/2000", "18/09/2012", "18/10/1991", "18/10/2001", 
"18/10/2005", "18/10/2012", "18/12/1981", "18/12/1992", "18/12/2008", 
"19/01/1957", "19/01/1971", "19/01/1974", "19/01/1984", "19/02/1975", 
"19/02/1985", "19/03/1972", "19/03/1984", "19/03/1999", "19/03/2010", 
"19/03/2013", "19/04/1971", "19/04/1996", "19/04/2000", "19/04/2006", 
"19/04/2013", "19/05/1999", "19/05/2009", "19/06/1985", "19/06/1989", 
"19/06/2002", "19/06/2006", "19/06/2008", "19/06/2013", "19/07/1980", 
"19/07/1982", "19/07/1985", "19/07/2013", "19/08/1969", "19/08/2013", 
"19/09/1973", "19/09/1975", "19/09/1977", "19/09/1978", "19/09/1979", 
"19/09/1988", "19/09/2001", "19/09/2002", "19/09/2003", "19/11/1996", 
"2/01/1975", "2/01/1986", "2/01/1996", "2/01/2007", "2/02/1973", 
"2/02/1977", "2/02/1989", "2/03/1982", "2/03/1995", "2/04/1974", 
"2/04/1976", "2/04/1980", "2/04/1984", "2/04/1985", "2/04/1996", 
"2/04/2003", "2/04/2004", "2/04/2013", "2/05/1981", "2/05/2008", 
"2/05/2011", "2/06/1982", "2/06/1992", "2/06/1997", "2/06/2009", 
"2/06/2010", "2/07/1974", "2/07/1985", "2/07/1986", "2/07/1987", 
"2/07/1999", "2/07/2008", "2/08/1971", "2/08/1993", "2/08/1996", 
"2/08/2004", "2/09/1977", "2/09/1998", "2/09/2013", "2/10/1986", 
"2/10/1987", "2/10/2008", "2/11/1971", "2/11/1981", "2/12/1939", 
"2/12/1959", "2/12/1974", "2/12/1982", "2/12/1986", "2/12/1992", 
"2/12/1998", "2/12/2011", "20/01/1983", "20/01/1984", "20/03/1974", 
"20/03/1998", "20/03/1999", "20/03/2001", "20/03/2003", "20/03/2006", 
"20/03/2009", "20/03/2013", "20/04/1993", "20/04/2012", "20/05/1982", 
"20/05/1989", "20/06/1988", "20/06/1991", "20/06/2001", "20/06/2002", 
"20/06/2005", "20/06/2007", "20/06/2008", "20/06/2013", "20/07/1973", 
"20/07/1989", "20/08/1980", "20/08/1991", "20/09/1971", "20/09/1974", 
"20/09/1978", "20/09/1988", "20/09/1993", "20/09/1994", "20/09/1996", 
"20/09/2000", "20/09/2005", "20/09/2012", "20/10/1981", "20/10/1999", 
"20/10/2000", "20/11/1995", "20/11/1996", "20/12/1983", "20/12/1991", 
"20/12/2012", "21/02/2001", "21/03/1969", "21/03/1975", "21/03/1977", 
"21/03/1979", "21/03/1984", "21/03/1987", "21/03/1988", "21/03/1995", 
"21/03/2000", "21/03/2001", "21/03/2003", "21/03/2007", "21/03/2013", 
"21/04/1980", "21/04/1981", "21/04/1990", "21/04/1999", "21/05/2012", 
"21/06/2007", "21/06/2010", "21/06/2013", "21/07/1977", "21/08/1985", 
"21/08/1992", "21/09/1973", "21/09/1978", "21/09/1989", "21/09/1992", 
"21/09/2009", "21/10/1993", "21/11/1981", "21/11/1985", "21/11/1990", 
"21/12/1953", "21/12/1981", "21/12/1990", "21/12/1995", "21/12/2000", 
"21/12/2009", "21/12/2012", "22/02/1973", "22/02/1974", "22/02/1979", 
"22/02/1983", "22/02/1999", "22/02/2000", "22/03/1977", "22/03/1983", 
"22/03/1985", "22/03/1987", "22/03/1993", "22/03/2000", "22/03/2001", 
"22/03/2004", "22/03/2011", "22/03/2012", "22/03/2013", "22/04/1969", 
"22/04/1985", "22/04/1998", "22/04/2013", "22/05/1968", "22/05/1972", 
"22/05/1978", "22/05/2002", "22/05/2012", "22/06/1972", "22/06/1978", 
"22/06/1982", "22/06/2004", "22/06/2010", "22/07/1981", "22/07/1988", 
"22/07/2010", "22/07/2013", "22/08/1973", "22/08/2001", "22/08/2013", 
"22/09/1983", "22/09/1992", "22/09/1996", "22/09/1998", "22/09/1999", 
"22/09/2004", "22/10/1974", "22/10/1976", "22/10/1985", "22/10/1986", 
"22/10/1991", "22/10/2012", "22/11/1967", "22/11/1983", "22/11/1984", 
"22/11/1995", "22/11/2012", "22/12/1982", "22/12/1983", "22/12/2011", 
"23/01/1976", "23/02/1978", "23/02/1982", "23/02/2000", "23/03/1977", 
"23/03/1984", "23/03/1994", "23/03/1998", "23/03/1999", "23/03/2000", 
"23/03/2001", "23/03/2006", "23/03/2009", "23/03/2011", "23/04/1981", 
"23/04/2007", "23/04/2013", "23/06/1998", "23/06/2005", "23/07/1979", 
"23/07/2002", "23/07/2013", "23/08/1974", "23/08/1982", "23/08/1985", 
"23/08/2005", "23/09/1974", "23/09/1975", "23/09/1985", "23/09/1986", 
"23/09/1992", "23/09/1994", "23/09/1996", "23/09/2003", "23/09/2009", 
"23/09/2010", "23/10/1979", "23/10/1986", "23/10/1989", "23/10/1991", 
"23/11/1973", "23/12/1977", "23/12/1982", "24/01/1967", "24/02/2000", 
"24/03/1988", "24/03/1993", "24/03/1997", "24/03/2000", "24/03/2005", 
"24/04/1978", "24/04/2012", "24/04/2013", "24/05/1977", "24/05/1982", 
"24/05/2002", "24/05/2006", "24/06/1974", "24/06/1981", "24/06/1982", 
"24/06/1983", "24/06/1992", "24/06/2009", "24/06/2013", "24/07/1972", 
"24/07/1992", "24/07/2008", "24/07/2013", "24/08/1978", "24/08/1983", 
"24/09/1984", "24/09/1986", "24/09/1992", "24/09/1996", "24/09/1997", 
"24/09/2008", "24/09/2009", "24/09/2011", "24/10/1973", "24/10/1979", 
"24/10/1984", "24/10/1985", "24/11/1986", "24/11/1994", "25/01/1977", 
"25/02/1994", "25/02/2013", "25/03/1969", "25/03/1975", "25/03/1977", 
"25/03/1986", "25/03/1993", "25/03/2010", "25/03/2013", "25/04/2013", 
"25/05/2002", "25/05/2007", "25/06/1984", "25/06/1985", "25/06/1999", 
"25/06/2002", "25/06/2008", "25/06/2013", "25/07/1972", "25/07/1977", 
"25/07/1980", "25/07/1987", "25/08/1969", "25/08/1980", "25/09/1974", 
"25/09/1980", "25/09/1985", "25/09/1992", "25/09/1995", "25/09/1996", 
"25/10/1976", "25/10/1980", "25/10/1984", "25/10/1991", "25/10/2005", 
"25/10/2007", "25/10/2010", "25/11/1971", "25/11/1985", "26/02/1994", 
"26/02/2013", "26/03/1977", "26/03/1978", "26/03/1980", "26/03/1985", 
"26/03/1992", "26/03/2001", "26/04/2011", "26/05/2010", "26/06/1969", 
"26/06/1985", "26/06/2001", "26/06/2002", "26/06/2003", "26/06/2013", 
"26/07/1990", "26/07/1999", "26/07/2002", "26/07/2013", "26/08/1977", 
"26/08/1980", "26/08/1996", "26/08/2013", "26/09/1974", "26/09/1978", 
"26/09/1989", "26/09/1995", "26/09/2001", "26/09/2005", "26/09/2011", 
"26/10/1978", "26/10/1985", "26/10/1993", "26/10/2005", "26/10/2010", 
"26/11/1971", "26/11/1984", "27/01/1988", "27/02/1984", "27/02/2003", 
"27/02/2013", "27/03/1984", "27/03/1992", "27/03/1995", "27/03/1998", 
"27/03/2001", "27/03/2003", "27/03/2012", "27/03/2013", "27/04/1971", 
"27/05/1976", "27/06/1978", "27/06/1982", "27/06/1985", "27/06/1986", 
"27/06/2006", "27/06/2013", "27/07/1971", "27/07/1983", "27/07/1995", 
"27/08/2012", "27/09/1973", "27/09/1985", "27/09/1988", "27/09/1993", 
"27/09/1995", "27/09/1999", "27/09/2002", "27/09/2005", "27/09/2011", 
"27/10/2006", "27/11/1997", "28/01/1976", "28/01/1983", "28/02/2002", 
"28/02/2013", "28/03/1977", "28/03/1982", "28/03/1983", "28/03/1990", 
"28/03/2000", "28/03/2003", "28/03/2006", "28/03/2012", "28/04/1976", 
"28/04/1977", "28/04/1978", "28/04/1983", "28/04/1987", "28/04/2002", 
"28/05/1980", "28/06/1977", "28/06/1985", "28/06/2006", "28/06/2013", 
"28/07/1982", "28/08/1978", "28/08/1991", "28/08/2012", "28/09/1992", 
"28/09/2000", "28/09/2006", "28/09/2011", "28/10/1985", "28/10/1986", 
"28/10/1991", "28/10/1993", "28/11/1976", "28/11/1979", "28/11/2001", 
"29/01/1953", "29/01/1969", "29/01/1998", "29/03/1974", "29/03/1977", 
"29/03/1979", "29/03/1993", "29/03/1999", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2012", 
"29/04/1977", "29/04/1978", "29/04/2002", "29/04/2009", "29/05/1978", 
"29/05/2013", "29/06/1984", "29/06/2005", "29/07/1975", "29/07/1980", 
"29/07/1996", "29/07/2013", "29/08/1978", "29/08/1985", "29/09/1978", 
"29/09/1983", "29/09/1992", "29/09/1999", "29/09/2009", "29/10/1976", 
"29/10/1985", "29/10/1986", "29/10/1987", "29/10/1995", "29/10/2002", 
"29/10/2004", "29/11/1995", "3/01/1975", "3/01/2007", "3/02/1976", 
"3/02/1989", "3/02/1992", "3/02/1997", "3/02/1999", "3/03/1969", 
"3/03/1982", "3/03/2003", "3/03/2004", "3/03/2008", "3/03/2010", 
"3/04/1992", "3/04/1996", "3/04/1997", "3/04/2002", "3/04/2003", 
"3/04/2012", "3/04/2013", "3/05/1973", "3/05/1990", "3/06/1976", 
"3/06/1982", "3/06/1993", "3/07/1986", "3/07/1996", "3/07/2002", 
"3/08/1975", "3/09/1975", "3/09/1985", "3/09/1992", "3/09/1996", 
"3/09/2007", "3/10/1973", "3/10/1975", "3/10/1979", "3/10/1980", 
"3/10/1988", "3/10/1989", "3/10/1990", "3/10/2006", "3/11/1968", 
"3/11/1970", "3/11/1986", "3/12/1981", "3/12/1982", "3/12/1993", 
"3/12/1997", "3/12/2002", "30/01/1999", "30/01/2006", "30/01/2007", 
"30/03/1977", "30/03/1992", "30/03/2001", "30/03/2011", "30/03/2012", 
"30/04/1956", "30/04/1980", "30/04/1998", "30/04/2001", "30/04/2004", 
"30/04/2010", "30/04/2011", "30/05/1995", "30/05/2000", "30/06/1976", 
"30/06/2004", "30/06/2009", "30/07/1980", "30/07/1982", "30/07/1984", 
"30/07/2001", "30/07/2013", "30/08/1976", "30/08/1978", "30/08/1982", 
"30/08/1985", "30/08/1989", "30/08/2002", "30/09/1971", "30/09/1974", 
"30/09/1980", "30/09/1992", "30/09/1998", "30/09/2011", "30/10/1978", 
"30/10/1986", "30/10/1991", "30/10/1995", "30/10/2001", "30/10/2003", 
"30/10/2006", "30/11/1978", "30/11/1995", "30/11/2010", "30/11/2012", 
"31/01/1980", "31/01/1991", "31/01/1997", "31/01/2006", "31/01/2013", 
"31/03/1977", "31/03/1992", "31/03/1995", "31/03/1998", "31/07/1986", 
"31/07/2013", "31/08/1978", "31/08/1979", "31/08/1982", "31/08/1983", 
"31/08/1993", "31/08/1999", "31/08/2012", "31/10/1984", "31/10/1986", 
"31/10/2006", "31/12/1982", "4/01/1982", "4/01/1990", "4/02/1970", 
"4/02/1980", "4/03/1971", "4/03/1994", "4/03/1996", "4/03/1998", 
"4/03/1999", "4/03/2013", "4/04/1974", "4/04/1991", "4/04/2003", 
"4/04/2005", "4/05/1981", "4/05/1982", "4/05/1985", "4/05/2004", 
"4/05/2010", "4/06/1993", "4/06/1997", "4/06/1998", "4/06/1999", 
"4/06/2002", "4/06/2003", "4/06/2013", "4/07/1985", "4/07/1986", 
"4/07/2002", "4/07/2005", "4/08/1977", "4/08/1982", "4/08/1983", 
"4/08/1986", "4/09/1978", "4/10/1968", "4/10/1971", "4/10/1974", 
"4/10/1977", "4/10/1982", "4/10/1996", "4/10/2001", "4/10/2012", 
"4/11/1977", "4/12/1976", "4/12/2000", "4/12/2006", "4/12/2007", 
"4/12/2008", "5/01/1983", "5/02/1965", "5/02/2009", "5/03/1974", 
"5/03/1981", "5/03/1987", "5/03/2002", "5/03/2010", "5/03/2013", 
"5/04/2001", "5/05/1981", "5/05/2010", "5/06/1969", "5/06/1985", 
"5/06/2013", "5/07/1975", "5/07/2007", "5/07/2012", "5/07/2013", 
"5/08/1986", "5/08/2002", "5/08/2004", "5/09/1977", "5/09/1978", 
"5/09/1991", "5/10/1993", "5/10/2005", "5/10/2011", "5/11/1969", 
"5/11/1979", "5/11/1981", "5/12/1972", "5/12/1973", "5/12/2006", 
"5/12/2012", "6/01/1994", "6/01/2012", "6/02/1970", "6/02/2006", 
"6/03/1989", "6/03/2000", "6/03/2001", "6/03/2003", "6/03/2012", 
"6/04/1978", "6/04/1994", "6/04/1998", "6/04/2000", "6/04/2009", 
"6/05/1969", "6/05/2003", "6/06/1984", "6/06/2013", "6/07/1977", 
"6/07/2007", "6/08/1967", "6/08/1973", "6/08/1982", "6/08/2013", 
"6/09/1973", "6/09/1977", "6/09/1978", "6/09/1988", "6/09/1999", 
"6/09/2005", "6/09/2011", "6/10/1983", "6/10/1985", "6/10/1986", 
"6/10/1987", "6/10/1988", "6/10/1993", "6/10/2004", "6/10/2011", 
"6/11/1976", "6/11/1981", "6/12/1977", "7/01/1986", "7/02/1995", 
"7/02/2006", "7/03/1974", "7/03/1978", "7/03/1979", "7/03/1983", 
"7/03/1985", "7/03/1989", "7/03/1991", "7/03/1997", "7/03/2000", 
"7/03/2005", "7/03/2011", "7/04/1976", "7/04/1979", "7/04/1986", 
"7/04/1987", "7/04/1998", "7/04/1999", "7/04/2005", "7/04/2006", 
"7/04/2008", "7/05/1975", "7/05/2010", "7/05/2012", "7/06/1971", 
"7/06/1995", "7/07/1977", "7/07/1982", "7/07/1986", "7/07/2010", 
"7/08/1980", "7/09/1978", "7/09/1989", "7/09/1999", "7/10/1971", 
"7/10/1977", "7/10/1987", "7/10/1993", "7/10/2003", "7/10/2008", 
"7/11/1970", "7/11/1980", "7/11/1984", "7/11/2000", "7/11/2001", 
"7/11/2002", "7/11/2006", "7/12/1976", "7/12/1978", "7/12/2000", 
"7/12/2005", "7/12/2012", "8/02/1968", "8/02/1990", "8/03/1974", 
"8/03/1978", "8/03/1979", "8/03/1988", "8/03/1989", "8/03/1993", 
"8/03/1994", "8/03/1995", "8/03/2001", "8/03/2003", "8/03/2013", 
"8/04/1981", "8/04/1982", "8/04/2008", "8/04/2009", "8/04/2010", 
"8/04/2013", "8/05/1981", "8/05/1986", "8/06/1979", "8/06/2001", 
"8/07/1975", "8/07/1982", "8/07/2010", "8/07/2013", "8/08/1990", 
"8/08/2009", "8/08/2013", "8/09/1978", "8/09/1988", "8/09/1997", 
"8/09/2000", "8/09/2006", "8/10/1985", "8/10/1986", "8/10/2002", 
"8/10/2003", "8/10/2009", "8/10/2012", "8/11/1970", "8/11/1996", 
"8/11/2000", "8/11/2002", "8/12/1977", "8/12/1987", "8/12/1988", 
"8/12/1995", "9/01/1971", "9/01/1985", "9/01/2012", "9/02/1970", 
"9/02/1982", "9/02/1990", "9/02/1996", "9/03/1982", "9/03/1988", 
"9/03/2009", "9/03/2010", "9/04/1986", "9/04/1991", "9/04/1996", 
"9/04/2013", "9/05/2012", "9/07/2008", "9/07/2013", "9/08/1991", 
"9/08/2002", "9/08/2013", "9/09/1975", "9/09/1982", "9/09/1993", 
"9/09/1997", "9/09/1998", "9/09/2008", "9/10/1991", "9/10/1996", 
"9/10/2003", "9/10/2012", "9/11/1976", "9/11/1992", "9/11/1999", 
"9/12/1988", "9/12/1997"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("neg_decimal_lat", 
"decimal_long", "max_drill_depth", "water_level_date"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code is as follows

```
require(ggplot2)
require('ggmap')
  plotdata <- plotdata[1:15, c("neg_decimal_lat", "decimal_long", 
                               "max_drill_depth", "water_level_date")]                                    
date <- factor(plotdata$water_level_date, 
levels=plotdata$water_level_date[!duplicated(plotdata$water_level_date)])

colormap <- c("darkblue","blue","lightblue", "green", 
               "yellow", "orange","darkorange", "red", "darkred")

depth <- c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50,60,70,80,90,100,110,  #legendrange
           120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190, 200, 300, 400,500,600, 700,
           800,900, 1000,1100,1200,1300,1400, 1500, 2400)
# static map drawn based on min max of latlong     
map.plot<- get_map(location = c(min(plotdata$decimal_long),
                                    min(plotdata$neg_decimal_lat),
                                    max(plotdata$decimal_long),
                                    max(plotdata$neg_decimal_lat)),
                      source = "osm", zoom=6)
     theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 8))
     static.map <- ggmap(map.plot) %+% plotdata + 
       aes(x = decimal_long,
           y = neg_decimal_lat,
           z = max_drill_depth) +
             stat_summary2d(fun = median, binwidth = c(.01, .01),alpha = 1) + 
             scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Drill Depth",colours = colormap, breaks=depth, 

labels = format(depth), space = "Lab") + 
    labs(x = "Longitude",y = "Latitude" )+ coord_map()
    Dates <- seq(as.Date("1985/1/1"), as.Date("1995/1/1"), "years")
#current loop for date
    for (i in seq_along(Dates)){    
    filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")
    print(static.map)
    ggsave(filename=filename,
            plot = static.map,
            scale = 4,
            width = 5, height = 3,
            dpi = 300)
    }
```

The overall aim is to get it for example to draw all points that were recorded in 1985-1986 and exclude all others, but also showing each month and the points are drawn at their specific month. These would be made into 12 images. **Also watch out as the loop is bugged and keeps printing more of the same map so don't forget to stop it.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A good reproducible example will help others to tackle your question lot more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reproducible example would help.  It is not clear what the problem is.
This seems to work:

```
Dates <- seq(as.Date("1985/1/1"), as.Date("1995/1/1"), "years")

for (i in seq_along(Dates)) {
  filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")
  print(filename)
}
```

Comment: That seems to work for me too only I think I stated my question incorrectly, the main thing I am trying to do is plot points based upon their latlong and I want to somehow draw the ones within a certain time period and exclude others that dont fall into the time line. I was just interested in how I could plot data based upon the dates. If you want I could upload the data and code I am using but its fairly messy.

Comment: Without seeing your data, I'd guess you want to subset your dataframe so that you are only working with the time frame of interest.  e.g. `DF[DF$Dates < as.Date("1990/1/1"),]`

Comment: The way I was thinking of doing it would be displaying plotted points which each have a depth, lat, long and date_recorded. The thing I am trying to do is make a date range to limit the rows to only those in that time frame then each month of the frame would then be plotted in its recorded month. Basically I am aiming for 12 plots, one for each month and the corresponding rows' lat long coords would be plotted according to the month the recording was made. Sorry If I've confused anyone at all I'm still trying figure it out myself.

Comment: @Cam.f: You need to give a reproducible example and a clear idea on what sort of plot you are trying to produce.  For example, you have 4 variables (depth, lat & long, and date), what are you trying to plot? depth by date (month), depth as lat/long by date?

Comment: ok, I will give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve so each row is plotted by x which is longitude and y which is latitude which is then colored based on the depth.(All this already works) The issue that I'm having is how to plot only points from a certain year. I've got my code now I was at home before so I didn't have access to it. I'll upload a small sample since my database is 4000> rows.